# How to change tab with selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

How to change tab with selenium? I am performing my automatic tests but when I click on a button, it opens a new tab. What I need is that selenium change tab and continue with automation. I'm using

```
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"2");
```

But it does not work and the code fails.

Answer (score 1):

**C#**

Use this code to open new tab & switch between tabs:

Use Waiter.

tabs index starts from 0 for 1st tab.

```
var body = Waiter.Until(ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.TagName("body"))).FirstOrDefault();
body.SendKeys(Keys.Control + 't');     //Opens new tab
var tabs = GlobalDriver.WindowHandles;
GlobalDriver.SwitchTo().Window(tabs[1]);
GlobalDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("Url");
```

The code is in *C#*

It will be somehow similar in *Java*, just the syntax will be different.

Hope this helps you!